# jquery show/hide with php for label/input text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Using php/jquery I'm listing out rows data from mysql db using php while loop

When I click on edit button on particular record the label is replaced with input text!! and label value is passed to input text but it showing up only in first row record I'm unable to replace particular row record from label to input.

I'm using 4 links button for edit/delete/save/cancel
when i click on edit button edit/delete button will change to save/cancel and vice versa.

Any help is appricated thanks!!

**jquery code**

```
$('body').delegate('.edit', 'click', function() {
    $('#feed_label').hide();
    $('#url1').show();
});

$('body').delegate('.cancel', 'click', function() {
    $('#feed_label').show();
    $('#url1').hide();
});
```

**html/php code**

```
<div>
    <label style="display:block-inline;" class="feed_label" id="feed_label" idl='<?php echo $row->id;?>'>
            <?php echo $row->url; ?>
    </label>
    <input name="url1" class="form-control url1" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>" id="url1" type="text" placeholder="http://feeds.com/" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div>
    <a ide='<?php echo $row->id;?>'  id="edit" class='edit' href="#" style="display:block-inline;">EDIT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a idu='<?php echo $row->id;?>' id="update" class='update btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='#' style='display:none;'>SAVE</a>
    <a idd='<?php echo $row->id;?>'  id="delete"    class='delete' href="#" style="display:block-inline;">DELETE</a>
    <a idc='<?php echo $row->id;?>' id="cancel" class='cancel btn btn-warning btn-sm' href='#' style='display:none;'>CANCEL</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well what are you trying to do?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem maybe because you are giving the same ids to all the rows in your table, you need to differentiate then and select accordingly.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I have row displayed from mysql db n ive placed edit button to replace label to input text to update individual record but when i click on other than 1st row that particular label value is sent to first row input text.. my requirment is clicked row label should replaced with input text i would be able to update it into my msql db any help appreciated thanks!!

Comment: @user3516962 thank you!! i guess that might my problem i have used ide/idu/idd/idc/ user defined atribute for my edit/delete/update oprations thanks!!